# Run application (on startup) in 64 bit machine

Tags: c#

C# application refuse to start when windows startup. As the machine is 64 bit. But when same application runs in 32 bit, Application starts without any fail when windows start.
Is there any settings to be done when installing the C# application in 64 bit so that it run in windows start up.

Comment: Its running. Problem is when machine starts this application not starts automaticallty in 64 bit

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's hardly clear.....I had to read it half a dozen times before I saw the *windows start up* bit.

Comment: does you app have 32-bit DLLs? You need to compile your app as x86 platform

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether the machine is 32 bit or 64 bit. You add an entry to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, either the 32 bit or 64 bit view, and the system will execute the command after the user logs in.

If your application is failing only on 64 bit systems, then most likely there is a problem with your application. You'll need to do some more debugging and gather diagnostics.